# Reference to ejs view files does not change after the build, although it combines it inside of production.js - Javascript MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, javascriptmvc, ejs

In the code we use something like this:

```
$('#wrapper').html('//app/views/content.ejs', {foo:"bar"});
```

And when we build the app, this still stays the same, although the content.ejs file is built into production.js.

So my question is, **what should we do so that when we build the app, these references point to ejs files inside of production.js?**

We are using JMVC 3.2.2

We've also tried using this way:

```
$('#wrapper').html( $.View('//app/views/content.ejs', {foo:"bar"}) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer in JMVC forum: https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/#Topic/32525000000958049

Credit to: Curtis Cummings

Answer:

> The paths to the views do not need to change.
>
> When the production.js file is created, your views are included and
>   get preloaded when the script runs. When you reference:
>   '//app/views/content.ejs', view first checks if the view file you are
>   requesting has been preloaded and if it has, will use that instead of
>   making a request for the .ejs file.

Answer (score 0):

Your views are not getting added to production.js; you need to steal each one of them:

```
steal('//app/views/content.ejs');
```

JMVC 3.1:

```
steal.views('//app/views/content.ejs');
```

Comment: Correct. And yes, this is what i'm doing. I got the answer on JMVC forum. I will post it now